Using cloudant-java-sdk in a webservice, should an instance of the client be shared or should an instance be created per request?
The Couldant-java-sdk docs say that it's thread safe, but don't recommend one way or the other, the code examples are simplified. I'm hoping for an answer from someone experienced with the library who can give a recommendation. The library readme recommends asking questions here.
It comes recommended to use this library with couchdb3 if using java though I'm considering just using making raw http queries instead.
